# RegEx in PHP array

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to iterate through an array of URI paths to insert an iOS smartBanner in those pages. One of the pages is dynamic and follows the path with an id. This is how I distinguish if it is a 'details' page and not a general list.

My challenge is that I need to identify the the path is followed by '/num'.

Here is my PHP code:

```
    <?php
$urls = array("/app/explore", "/app/dashboard", "app/members", "/app/account-settings", "/app/jobs");
  foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $value ) { ?>
      <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1111111111">
    <?php }
  }
?>
```

First I create the array of paths that I want to target. However the last path "app/jobs" is actually supposed to be "app/jobs/{numeric id}". In other words "app/jobs/1234", where "1234" can be any number.

So I need to somehow use regex for that last object in the array to represent "app/jobs/(any number)".

Can anyone advise on how I might accomplish this?

Would it be easier to take that out and use a separate if statement?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Have you tried any regexs yet? Maybe `~app/jobs/\d+~`?

Comment: Hi Chris 85, Do you mean to just add that to the array as a string literal, like this: $urls = array("/app/explore", "/app/dashboard", "app/members", "/app/account-settings", "app/jobs/\d+~");   How will the browser know to parse the regex portion ' \d+~ ' ?  I thought I may need to add some function call for that, like this:  $urls = array("/app/explore", "/app/dashboard", "app/members", "/app/account-settings", "/app/jobs" + evaluate('  \d+~ ')); How does that work? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **preg_match** Here the simple example :

```
echo preg_match("/app\/jobs\/(\d+)/","app/jobs/1234/"); //this will return 1 
echo preg_match("/app\/jobs\/(\d+)/","app/jobs"); //this will return 0
echo preg_match("/app\/jobs\/(\d+)/","app/jobs/aaa/"); //return 0
```

**preg_match** will returning 1 if the regex matches with given string and return 0 if it does not.